# How can I output information from a python script to a Node.js script?

Tags: python, node.js, data-transfer, cross-language

I am making a twitter bot, and I want to generate text from a python script, and then send that information to a Node JS script. I have everything figured out, on how to generate the text and everything, I just need to know how to get the generated text to my JS script.

I'm am using textgenrnn(https://github.com/minimaxir/textgenrnn) to generate text, and I'm pretty sure that it is python exclusive.

Comment: Please refer to [how to ask a good question in stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to attach any code or attempt that you have made so far, with the errors or unexpected behaviors that you find during the execution of your code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was my first post. I found this article that solved my problem:  https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/